# Installation of the theme using putty

Tags: magento2, theme, installation, putty

[image]I am using puTTY and its showing the error. [image: inside var/www/demo/app folder is situated]

Comment: Does it work without the PHP at the start? "bin/magento setup:upgrade". 
What php version is returned with "php -v" ?

Comment: I just had another thought, when you install a theme, copy the files to the relevant directory, then goto the admin panel and view the theme from there **before** running the setup command. When you visit the admin page, it adds the theme to the database.

Comment: Please check app folder it have not proper required file exist.

Comment: Check app/bootstrap.php exis or not?

Comment: the admin panel is throwing exceptions.

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The XML in file "/var/www/demo/app/code/Stathmos/MetalPrices/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml" is invalid:
Element 'config', attribute '{https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation': The attribute '{https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation' is not allowed.
Line: 2

Verify the XML and try again.

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The XML in file "/var/www/demo/app/code/Stathmos/MetalPrices/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml" is invalid:

Comment: @Chris its not showing in the admin panel and moreover it stopped running .

Comment: @GohilRajesh  bootstrap file exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found you are not uploaded your theme propely in magento.

please upload it in proper path folder.

```
app/code
app/design
pub/media
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try executing below mentioned command.

```
sudo php bin/magento setup:upgrade && 
sudo php bin/magento setup:di:compile && 
sudo php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f && 
sudo php bin/magento indexer:reindex && sudo chown 777 -R var/* pub/* generated/* && 
sudo php bin/magento c:f && 
sudo chown -R $USER:www-data ../demo/
```

Comment: I tried and its throwing this exception

Comment: 1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The XML in file "/var/www/demo/app/code/Stathmos/MetalPrices/etc/adminhtml/routes.xml" is invalid:
Element 'config', attribute '{https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation': The attribute '{https://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance}noNamespaceSchemaLocation' is not allowed.
Line: 2

Verify the XML and try again.

Comment: https://www.mageplaza.com/kb/how-to-install-a-new-theme-magento-2.html#:~:text=%20To%20install%20a%20New%20Theme%20in%20Magento,on%20Themeforest.%20On%20the%20Admin%20panel%2C...%20More%20 i followed for the installation

Comment: @kks looks like your theme either having an issue or its folders are not placed properly. can your paste here you theme path which you downloaded from the net?